# How to convert and report time read in ps to frequency in Hz or MHz or KHz in VHDL?

Tags: vhdl

In the VHDL test bench, declared
'''
t1 : time;
t2 : time;
'''
The simulation is in picoseconds. The assignment in architecure is
'''
t1: now -- assign time to t1
t2: now -- assign time to t2 later point in test bench.
'''
Question :
How to convert the delta time in ps (t2-t1) to frequency? Either Hz or MHz or KHz, does not matter.

Comment: An integer of what? seconds? us? ns? ps? fs?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] and read "[ask]" to learn how this site works. -- What did you try to convert a string to a time or integer value? Which functions did you find by reading VHDL documentation, and why don't they work for you? Please [edit] your question if you add new information.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a special way to do this in VHDL - physical types like `time` are designed to make unit conversions simpler, not to swap between different sorts of physical quantities.

What that means is that you're going to need to implement some steps to do the conversion, whether in a function or as part of a sequential process. You could even define a `frequency` type if you're so inclined.

To do the conversion:

1. Convert the time value into a quantity of type `integer`. This is done by dividing by another span of time. Which you pick will determine the accuracy of your calculations, but `1 fs` is the fundamental time unit and will give you the highest granularity.
2. Convert the integer into `real` and perform the *f* = 1/*t* calculation to get a value for the frequency as a `real` value.
3. If you need to, multiply by the appropriate power of 10 to get your desired units and cast back to `integer` if that's what you're after (if you define a `frequency` type, you could assign units, and it will have the same conversion support that `time` has).